# Enable button when user picks a category in the selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to enable a button when the user picks an option in the selector. I've set a hidden option with a value of "". This is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#minus-btn").attr('disabled','disabled');

 $('#pref-list').change(function() {
   var selected = $(this).val();
   if(selected != ''){
     $('#pref-text').removeClass('hidden');
     $('#pref-list-d').removeClass('col-xs-2');
     $('#pref-list-d').addClass('col-xs-1');
     $('#pref-list-p').addClass('col-xs-1');

   } else {
       $("#minus-btn").removeAttr('disabled','disabled');

   }

   })

});
```

This is my html:

```
div class="container-fluid">

    <form method="POST" class="form-group">
        <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-3" id="pref-list-m">
        <button id="minus-btn"><i id="minus-icon" class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-1" id="pref-list-p">
        <button id="plus-btn"><i id="plus-icon" class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-2" id="pref-list-d">
        <select class="btn-sm custom" id="pref-list" name="preferences">
            <option value="" hidden> Elige </option>
            <option value="deportes">Deportes</option>
            <option value="peliculas">Peliculas</option>
            <option value="carros">Carros</option>
            <option value="Libros">Libros</option>
            <option value="Colores">Colores</option>
        </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-2" id="pref-text-d">
                <input type="text" class="hidden form-control pull-left" placeholder=" item1,item2,item3" id="pref-text">
        </div>

        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-default0" id="nextstep" value="Siguiente">
        </div>
</div>
```

It does not enable the button when I attempt to remove the attribute. Please help me fix this.

Thank you.

Comment: does anything happen at all? are you sure the block is being entered? what does a hidden input have to do with the question? removeAttr only takes one argument, the name of the attribute.

Comment: The hidden input has nothing to do with the question, just the removeAttr

Comment: Provide relevant html as per [mcve]

Comment: I will edit it right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Anirudha asked to use `$("#minus-btn").prop('disabled', true);`, it is working with it.

Need to add enable code `$("#minus-btn").prop('disabled', true);` , if `selected != ''`

Example Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#minus-btn").prop('disabled', true);

  $('#pref-list').change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    if (selected != '') {
      $('#pref-text').removeClass('hidden');
      $('#pref-list-d').removeClass('col-xs-2');
      $('#pref-list-d').addClass('col-xs-1');
      $('#pref-list-p').addClass('col-xs-1');
      $("#minus-btn").prop('disabled', false); //update / add this line

    } else {
      $("#minus-btn").prop('disabled', true);

    }

  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">

  <form method="POST" class="form-group">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-3" id="pref-list-m">
        <button id="minus-btn"><i id="minus-icon" class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true">This sbutton</i>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-1" id="pref-list-p">
        <button id="plus-btn"><i id="plus-icon" class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-2" id="pref-list-d">
        <select class="btn-sm custom" id="pref-list" name="preferences">
          <option value="" hidden>Elige</option>
          <option value="deportes">Deportes</option>
          <option value="peliculas">Peliculas</option>
          <option value="carros">Carros</option>
          <option value="Libros">Libros</option>
          <option value="Colores">Colores</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-2" id="pref-text-d">
        <input type="text" class="hidden form-control pull-left" placeholder=" item1,item2,item3" id="pref-text">
      </div>

    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-default0" id="nextstep" value="Siguiente">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: removeAttr() only takes one argument...the arributeName

Comment: That worked. I used prop correctly but i used removeAttr('disabled','disabled'). That was why it wasn't working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try to use prop instead of removeAttr function, something like this

```
else {
       $("#minus-btn").prop('disabled',true);
   }
```

Comment: And when you set to disable use prop too

Comment: I'll give it a try

Comment: @DiegoRios chedck this, it should work https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-disable-enable-a-form-element/